# Should we leave crash logs as is?

Tags: discussion

On many questions, help is asked about how a game has crashed. Following how it happened a long string of java code appears and takes up a large space in the page. Would it be bad to paste the code to a site like [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and link it or is that frowned upon. Here are some posts to what I'm talking about.

- [Minecraft will not run with any version. Please Help!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144715/minecraft-will-not-run-with-any-version-please-help)

Or is it better to place it as preformatted text like this.

- [Minecraft Forge 1.6.4 not working on Minecraft 1.7.2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144598/minecraft-forge-1-6-4-not-working-on-minectaft-1-7-2)

And help or advice in order to better the editing in these types of questions?

Comment: Post has been edited to remove ugly formatting. Perhaps you could link to an older revision?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the preformatted text or 'code' section handles it fairly nicely. If it gets above a certain length, it automatically adds scrollbars so as not to make the question body too long, whilst also maintaining the full crash log.

[image: paste code, select it and hit the 'code' button or CTRL-K]
([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks))

We also prefer our question/answer bodies to have all the information contained on our site, mainly to prevent link-rot, but also to avoid having users click away from the question/answer (and by extension, the site) itself.

Having said that, I don't have anything wrong with lengthy crash logs pasted into pastebin and linked here, but I don't think we should go out of our way to convert ones already here.

So to summarise, if a crash log is:

- Outside of code blocks: **BAD**, edit it into code blocks
- On pastebin: **OK**, leave alone
- Inside code blocks: **OK**, leave alone

Further reading:

- [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Works for me thanks a lot.